# Serving Static Files with Nginx, Flask, and Gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm hosting a Python Flask app with Gunicorn and reverse proxying with Nginx and I'm having a fair bit of difficulty serving static files using Nginx. Basically, when I navigate to a url like www.example.com/ or www.example.com/something, Nginx serves the static files fine. However, for any url with multiple / it fails to serve all static files (e.g. www.example.com/something/else does not render any static files -- css, js, images, etc). Regardless of the route I want to serve static files from the SAME directory (every template uses the same CSS and JS). How do I do that? I thought setting the root or aliasing to that directory would be sufficient.

I know there's another stack overflow post that says something similar but the solution doesn't actually address the problem (the asker just says they found the bug elsewhere), so any guidance is appreciated. Here's my current Nginx config for the app:

```
server{

    server_name 0.0.0.0 example.com www.example.com;
    root /path/to/project;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/project/project.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }

    location /css/ {
        autoindex on;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types; # mime.types exists 
    }

    location /js/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        alias /path/to/project/js/;
    }
    location /images/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        alias /path/to/project/images/;
    }
```

I realize that some of that is redundant and probably could be done better, I'm moreso just trying to demonstrate the various ways I've attempted at serving these files. I'm new to this so any advice or clerical questions are appreciated as well.

Comment: Look at the access log to determine what URI your application is requesting. The common problem is using path-relative URLs in the HTML file to specify the resource files.

Comment: @RichardSmith So the access logs show what I expected -- on a route like /something/else, nginx attempts to serve the static files from /something/css/stylesheet.css. Why is that the case (I'd like to understand this all a bit better), and how could I strip everything before the desired location? I imagine you could use rewrite, I'm just not privy to how one might do that

Comment: This isn't an Nginx problem. The access log is showing you that the flask app is asking for it's resource files using the wrong URL. You need to fix the definition of `css/stylesheet.css` in the flask app, probably by changing it to `/css/stylesheet.css`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Awesome, that worked for me! So, tangentially related question then, the way I'm getting my html is exporting via Webflow, so all of the src and href attributes for link and image tags are formatted without a leading / -- do you know of any way for flask to interpret these routes the same as if there were a leading slash? Originally I had some clunky javascript that rewrote the paths for all of these files, but that killed the load time of the page